# Start vim with NERDTree like we do Visual Studio Code/Sublime

Tags: neovim, plugin-nerdtree

I have decided to learn `vim` and want to give it a go for a month. I am about a week in, and it has been OK. I say "OK" because I do run into the usual frustrations that a n00b might run into.

Before `vim`, I used Visual Studio Code, and let's say I am in my project's directory: `/home/jwan/code/bejebeje.admin`

Whilst in that directory in the terminal I would run `code .` and that would open Visual Studio code with all my files in the left pane.

I read that `NERDTree` can give me that, so I've installed it and I have tried to configure it, but I must be doing something wrong, cause it isn't giving me that workflow that VS Code gave me.

According to the [NERDTree docs](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree), I need:

```
" Start NERDTree when Vim is started without file arguments.
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists('s:std_in') | NERDTree | endif
```

That comment sounds like what I want! Unless it thinks the dot `.` in `vim .` counts as a file argument, in which case maybe that doesn't apply!? I'm not sure.

Anyways, I went ahead and tried it. In my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` I have:

```
fun! TrimWhitespace()
  let l:save=winsaveview()
  keeppatterns %s/\s\+$//e
  call winrestview(l:save)
endfun

augroup custom_group
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePre * :call TrimWhitespace()
  autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
  autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists('s:std_in') | NERDTree | endif
augroup end
```

I believe it is OK to have it in the `augroup` since that rus automatically, at least that's the understanding I have.

So I saved that and exited `vim` and restarted it. But I don't get `NERDTree` with a pane to the right, I just get what I believe is `vim`'s own file browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Caveat: I use vim, not neovim, and don't use NERDTree.  However, it may be helpful to note that starting vim with `vim .` opens `.` in the first buffer, which by default uses the netrw plugin to display a directory listing.  Therefore `argc()` will equal `1`, causing your `autocmd VimEnter` not to fire.  You can check this by doing `vim .` then `:echo argc()`.

Comment: Opening vim with no arguments means just executing `vim`: this may be the use you are striving for?

Comment: Good read if you’re interested in the possibility of a different workflow altogether: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/

Comment: I'm sold! thank you very much @D.BenKnoble

Comment: Np; if you do solve/answer your question, please add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ditched NERDTree in favour of the netrw and the workflow [described here](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/). Make sure you watch them video casts too, they were super helpful.